# Python get version of C library when importing with ctypes

Tags: python, c

I have a C library compiled in different versions.  I'm creating a symbolic link, for my python program, to the particular version of the library I want.  Is there a way of getting the version of the library that's being loaded into python?

Here's how I'm loading the C library

```
import os
import ctypes as C

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
_foolib = C.cdll.LoadLibrary(path + "/foolib/libfoo.so")
```

Here `libfoo.so` is symbolically linked to any of the `libfoo.so.x.y.z`. I don't want to change the code to point to the new library  I only want to change the symbolic link.

Thanks

Comment: You could resolve the symbolic link (see `readlink`) or if the library provides a version variable/function, use that after it has loaded.

Comment: Didn't even cross my mind to use `readlink`.  I like it, if you put it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could resolve the symbolic link (see readlink) or if the library provides a version variable/function, use that after it has loaded.